# Razer Dark Shark issue with microphone noise and IPhone incompatibility

Tags: audio, microphone, headset

Ηello
I own a Razer Dark Shark headset. 
Ever since I bought it, I have issues with the microphone which makes a very loud and anoying noise with the slightest of movement. For instance, when I'm talking over skype, if I try to move my head this sound apears and is very anoying for the one(s) in the call with me, although I cannot hear it at all. The same happends when I try to adjust the mic or in general there is any movement to the connection it makes with the headset. I tried detaching it, and blowing in the socket as well as cleaning the jack with a soft cloth but yet again, no improvement at all.

How can I stop the anoying noise comming form the mic and what could possibly be the cause?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it use optical audio or is it 3.5mm/rca/other? How long have you had the headset? Same issue with any other headsets? Same issue with same headset on any other computer?

Comment: @jatuttle0 Oh im sorry I forgot to metnion these bits of info! It uses a standard 3.5mm jack, I had it for about a year now, and i suspected it might be the spliter (single to double jack) so i bought a new one but it wasn't it, and all other headsets work atreat. Even when i pluged the heaset and instead of the headset mic i pluged an external one, everything worked perfectly fine. And unfortunately I havent tested on other computers, but ill do that ASAP!
Thanks!